# typeclasses, overloading and instance declaration

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

Having this:

```
data Rectangle = Rectangle Height Width
data Circle = Circle Radius

class Shape a where
    area :: a -> Float
    perimeter :: a -> Float

instance Shape Rectangle where
    area (Rectangle h w) = h * w
    perimeter (Rectangle h w) = 2*h+w*2

instance Shape Circle where
    area (Circle r) = pi * r**2
    perimeter (Circle r) = 2*pi*r

volumenPrism base height = (area base) * height

surfacePrism shape h = (area shape) * 2 + perimeter shape * h
```

Why cant I write this? `a` is a type so why doesn't this work?

```
instance (Shape a) => Eq a where
      x==y = area x == area y
```

Obviously doing like this:

```
instance Eq Circle where
     x==y = area x == area y
```

first for Circle and then for Rectangle works..but it seems not the right way.

What is it I don't get in all this?

Ty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the type class instance resolution machinery doesn't backtrack. So if you write `instance Shape a => Eq a`, then whenever the compiler wants to find an `Eq` instance, the compiler will try to use this instance and for most types it won't work out because they aren't instances of `Shape`.

If you still really want to do this, you can add

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
```

at the top of your source file.

You can also work round some of the problems described above by also adding `OverlappingInstances` to the set of LANGUAGE pragmas, but you will still have a global instance for `Eq` that will cause significant confusion elsewhere in your program.

It's much better to just enumerate the instances you really need, even if it seems ugly. You can keep the boilerplate to a minimum with a helper function, e.g.

```
x `areaEq` y = area x == area y
```

and then

```
instance Eq Circle where
    (==) = areaEq
```

etc.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't backtrack - it's that it doesn't mean what you think it does.  `instance Shape a => Eq a` means "All types are instances of Eq with this definition. Using this instance causes a `Shape` constraint to be added for the type in use."

Comment: That's the only thing it can mean, by the way, given the open world assumption. An instance can always be added later that would make things ambiguous, no matter how careful you are.

Comment: Operationally, resolution doesn't bactrack. Semantically, instances are defined as you describe. Not really sure which is cause and effect :-) The open world assumption is already bent quite badly by e.g. `IncoherentInstances` so I don't it all follows completely naturally from that though.